# Input type "number" won't resize

Tags: html, text, input, resize, numbers

Why won't my input resize when I change the type to `type="number"` but it works with `type="text"`?

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ex5JZ/1/)

```
    Email: <input type="text" name="email" size="10"><br/>
  number: <input type="number" name="email" size="10">
```

Answer (score 107):

Seem like the `input` type `number` does not support `size` attribute or it's not compatible along browsers, you can set it through CSS instead:

```css
input[type='number']{
    width: 80px;
}
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ex5JZ/2/)**

Comment: Excellent! this does the job. Also one other little thing I've just noticed. The number type also doesn't allow a max limit of number where as the text does. Is there a way to fix that also?

Comment: It does support it, you can see all the supported value here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.number.html

Comment: I've got `maxlength="4"` and it isn't taking effect where as it is with `text`

Comment: Oh, the `maxlength` does not supported, only the `max` attribute.

Comment: If you want to target specific sizes use: `input[type=number][size="3"]{ width: 3em; }` etc.

Comment: To follow up on what nick said, you should use 1em more than your size otherwise it is blocked by your increment/decrement arrows.

Answer (score 68):

Incorrect usage.

Input type number it's made to have selectable value via arrows up and down.

So basically you are looking for **"width" CSS style.**

Input text historically is formatted with monospaced font, so size it's also the width it takes.

Input number it's new and "size" property has no sense at all*. A typical usage:

```
<input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="5">
```

[w3c docs](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_input_types.asp)

to fix, add a style:

```
<input type="number" name="email" style="width: 7em">
```

EDIT: if you want a range, you have to set `type="range"` and not `="number"`

EDIT2: *size is not an allowed value (so, no sense).
Check out official [W3C specifications](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_size.asp)

> Note: The size attribute works with the following input types: text,
>   search, tel, url, email, and password.
>
> Tip: To specify the maximum number of characters allowed in the
>    element, use the maxlength attribute.

Comment: Saying size in number inputs "has no use at all" is a stretch. If you have a number input with usual values between 2 to 4 (which is very common) you have no way to control the standard size and the whole thing is huge. Inputs never get any love, it seems... So the "solution" is just using text, even though you really only want numbers. Not every page design is based around making all inputs take a huge width and having to specify all number input's widths is a regression.

Comment: Input are inputs. Just add some size-related css attributes. 'small' 2em, 'medium' 4em,large 10em and so on, then add to your input, css styles will works where you want. 'size' it's about how space a free text must to take in the line: a number is not 'free', has range, an user wants to see the whole number, not only a part, so if you know how many digits it's that number, use the range attribute, since it's powerfull and number related

Comment: And that's exactly what the size attribute is for, it does a much better job than filling all inputs with classes and your entire css with dozens of sizes while calculating all of the different input differences through browsers :) (and no, range has nothing to do with it)

Comment: Size does not works with number, so what's the point? Just use a generic rule (like the accepted answer) if your scope it's to minimize custom styles. In real scenarios, not homework ones,  you can use a container box to assign a width rule to all its child-elements input[type=number]. I worked on various 500k/visit italian websites and that's the technique, so again,  size it's just a legacy approach for old spec of html and it's related to text, not number specialized input

Comment: The point is it was stupid to remove size, it was not because "it has no use".

Comment: @Forty you can forward your opinion to W3C. Size in HTML5 is a not allowed feature, just check for more explanation answer of Jukka K. Korpela. Size has really no use, it affected the width of input as SIDE EFFECT, side effects are just things to avoid while programming and I think you misunderstood Stackoverflow's goals... I just explained what did W3C and how to solve the question.

Comment: I am aware. My comment had the intention of clarifying that what you included in your answer is incorrect.

Comment: Again, NO! https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_size.asp Note: The size attribute works with the following input types: text, search, tel, url, email, and password.

Tip: To specify the maximum number of characters allowed in the <input> element, use the maxlength attribute.". So what's the point to downvote?

Comment: Fantastic fix, `style='width:80'` thank you so much

Answer (score 32):

Rather than set the length, set the max and min values for the number input.

The input box then resizes to fit the longest valid value.

If you want to allow a 3-digit number then set 999 as the max

```
 <input type="number" name="quantity" min="0" max="999">
```

Comment: This was the only method I could get to work for mobile Chrome on Android.

Comment: This is the correct answer. If you use CSS to specify an exact width, it might not look as you intend in all browsers. (Some will use wider up and down arrows, for instance.) Unless you need fixed dimensions, the safest way to do this is to let the browser choose the width based on the allowable values.

Comment: This creates to wide box for xx-large font size. Box width is so big that it shows also 999999 even if max=999 is used. How to fix?

Comment: Using Chrome 115 in 2023, and setting the max attribute does not seem to affect the width of the rendered input box at all.

Answer (score 7):

For [`<input type=number>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#number-state-%28type=number%29), by the HTML5 CR, the `size` attribute is not allowed. However, in [Obsolete features](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#obsolete) it says: “Authors should not, but may despite requirements to the contrary elsewhere in this specification, specify the maxlength and size attributes on input elements whose type attributes are in the Number state. One valid reason for using these attributes regardless is to help legacy user agents that do not support input elements with type="number" to still render the text field with a useful width.”

Thus, the `size` attribute can be used, but it only affects older browsers that do not support `type=number`, so that the element falls back to a simple text control, `<input type=text>`.

The rationale behind this is that the browser is expected to provide a user interface that takes the other attributes into account, for good usability. As the implementations may vary, any size imposed by an author might mess things up. (This also applies to setting the width of the control in CSS.)

The conclusion is that you should use `<input type=number>` in a more or less fluid setup that does not make any assumptions about the dimensions of the element.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is [`maxlength`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#htmlattrdefmaxlength).

> Valid for `text`, `search`, `url`, `tel`, `email`, and `password`, it defines the maximum number of characters (as UTF-16 code units) the user can enter into the field. This must be an integer value 0 or higher. If no maxlength is specified, or an invalid value is specified, the field has no maximum length. This value must also be greater than or equal to the value of minlength.

You might consider using one of these `input` types.

Answer (score 0):

Use min and max value instead of using size for "number" type, Input box size will be auto adjusted according to max value.

eg:
number:

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to set the `input` type `number` field length to a certain number of characters (and not pixels) you can do it in the following way:

```
input[type=number] {
    width: 7ch; /* 7 characters width */
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use an on onkeypress event. Example for a zip code box. It allows a maximum of 5 characters, and checks to make sure input is only numbers.

Nothing beats a server side validation of course, but this is a nifty way to go.

```js
function validInput(e) {
  e = (e) ? e : window.event;
  a = document.getElementById('zip-code');
  cPress = (e.which) ? e.which : e.keyCode;

  if (cPress > 31 && (cPress < 48 || cPress > 57)) {
    return false;
  } else if (a.value.length >= 5) {
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

```css
#zip-code {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 60px;
}
```

```html
<label for="zip-code">Zip Code:</label>
<input type="number" id="zip-code" name="zip-code" onkeypress="return validInput(event);" required="required">
```

Answer (score -3):

change type="number" to type="tel"