# How to fix width of input[type=number] in Chrome?

Tags: css

It looks like Webkit browsers (tried desktop Chrome and Safari) force set width to `input[type=number]` elements when you indicate both `min` and `max` attributes (i.e. when browser can calculate a width required to contain a potential value).

But what's worse is that sometimes a container width is affected also. How can one eliminate this behavior?

Here is the example: http://cssdeck.com/labs/mc5is9ja (see the difference between two `input[type=number]` elements).

(No such behavior observed in Firefox)

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but the answer matches both cases. I wasn't aware of this happening with number inputs. It's interesting behaviour, but the lower-scored answer on that other question makes it all clear (https://stackoverflow.com/a/22710090/1317805).

Comment: @JamesDonnelly the answer proposes to set "width" style directly to input, but in my case input width is defined by container, not vice versa (desired behavior).

Comment: In your case, `width: 100px` to `max-width: 100px`.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Wow, thanks! Why does it work?