# How do I change the input box size if the input type is number?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make the input box smaller by using maxlength and size, but it doesn't work if type="number", I noticed that by changing that type from number to text it does work. Normally I would just change the type but I also want the input to be numbers only. So far I have this:

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>somthing</legend>
    <label for="IPaddr">something</label>
    <input type="number" id="IPaddr" name="IPaddr" maxlength="3" size="3">.
    <input type="number" id="IPaddr" name="IPaddr" maxlength="3" size="3">.
    <input type="number" id="IPaddr" name="IPaddr" maxlength="3" size="3">.
    <input type="number" id="IPaddr" name="IPaddr" maxlength="3" size="3">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Side note, IDs **must** be unique

Comment: Does this answer your question? [maxlength ignored for input type="number" in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18510845/maxlength-ignored-for-input-type-number-in-chrome)

Comment: I think this old post should help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22709792/input-type-number-wont-resize

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Input type "number" won't resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22709792/input-type-number-wont-resize)

Comment: yeah i think i fixed it, thanks guys